# Is there a way to fetch the query plan for or insights about any specific SOSL execution?

Tags: developer-console, sosl, queryplan

Is there an alternate way to fetch the query plan of a SOSL execution (other than thru Developer Console > Query Editor)? My objective is to get some insights about any specific SOSL execution (like how query plan helps me with SOQL). I'm running into the following error (see screen shot below) while trying to view the query plan of a SOSL execution.

> Malformed Query - Unexpected token: FIND

[image]

I've tried this in both Developer editions orgs as well as sandboxes. Query Plan button seems to invoke the following REST API.

> /services/data/v56.0/tooling/query/?explain=FIND
> {"Joe Smith" OR "Joe Smythe"} IN Name Fields RETURNING lead(name,
> phone), contact(name, phone)

On observing the REST API response using network trace or workbench, the response received matches the error shown in the screenshot above. May be query plan for SOSL is not supported? But [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_tab_query_editor_query_plans.htm&type=5) seems to indicate otherwise.

> To get Query Plans for SOQL queries or SOSL searches, enter your query
> and click the Query Plan button in the Query Editor.

Comment: I would have been quite surprised if this did work (and wonder if that is a copy and paste mistake in the docs) since SOSL doesn't use traditional queries but rather uses index searches using something like lucene under the hood.

Comment: @PhilW I was hoping it would throw some details to help me optimize the SOSL (like how query plan gives me some insights into SOQL execution). Updated my question.

Comment: Closest I've seen, which I presume you have as well, is: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm

Comment: @Girbot Yes, I've seen this.